# Python telebot. Номер телефона в inlineButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Можно ли как-то в InlineKeyboardButton закинуть номер телефона? Чтобы по нажатию на кнопку пользователь мог сделать вызов.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного порывшись в Telethon Api -> https://tl.telethon.dev/types/phone/phone_call.html
Там есть метод который вызывает звонок.